# Optimizing Android built in Text to Speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I've been using android text to speech and I have it working well, but the voice never sounds as good as I would like it to. I understand its never going to sound "natural" but does anyone have any suggestions or know of any ways to make it sound more human or at least understandable.

I know you can adjust the pitch and rate and language. Are there any other adjustments that can be made? or even a better text to speech API that sounds better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't improve TTS quality. Even changing the pitch is dangerous. If you set it too low the TTS sounds terrible.

The only way to get a better voice would be to use a service that is not google such as [ispeech](http://www.ispeech.org/developers)

Answer (score 0):

Android text to speech supports multiple voices, the ones installed with your phone will vary depending on the model. One of my Nexus phones had excellent voices, but every (non-nexus) phone since then has had poor ones. You can change the active voice and download more voices in Settings->Language & [varies]->Text-to-speech output. Google's range seems to be limited to poor quality voices at the moment. You can also download paid for voices and/or engines from the likes of Svox, Pico and Ivona.